# Using Optaplanner VRP example with optaplanner-spring-boot-starter

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to create an app to solve VRP problems, and I'm getting this error msg when I use the domain classes from the VRP example code. in version 8.19.0.Final

"A planning entity is an instance of a class (class com.test.vrp.domain.Vehicle) that is not configured as a planning entity class ([class com.test.vrp.domain.Customer, class com.test.vrp.domain.timewindowed.TimeWindowedCustomer]).

```
If that class (Vehicle) (or superclass thereof) is not a @PlanningEntity annotated class, maybe your @PlanningSolution annotated class has an incorrect @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty or @PlanningEntityProperty annotated member.
Otherwise, if you're not using the Quarkus extension or Spring Boot starter, maybe that entity class (Vehicle) is missing from your solver configuration."

The Vehicle class is not configured as planning entity class, although it implements "Standstill" which is annotated as a Planning Entity.
```

Any changes I make (like annotating Vehicle as a Planning Entity) just create other errors.

```
2022-04-04 15:49:24.464 ERROR 8264 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] c.test.vrp.web.rest.PlannerResource  : Illegal argument: [] in getSolution()
2022-04-04 15:49:24.464 ERROR 8264 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] c.test.vrp.web.rest.PlannerResource  : Exception in getSolution() with cause = 'NULL' and exception = 'A planning entity is an instance of a class (class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.Vehicle) that is not configured as a planning entity class ([class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.Customer, class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.timewindowed.TimeWindowedCustomer]).
If that class (Vehicle) (or superclass thereof) is not a @PlanningEntity annotated class, maybe your @PlanningSolution annotated class has an incorrect @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty or @PlanningEntityProperty annotated member.
Otherwise, if you're not using the Quarkus extension or Spring Boot starter, maybe that entity class (Vehicle) is missing from your solver configuration.'

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A planning entity is an instance of a class (class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.Vehicle) that is not configured as a planning entity class ([class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.Customer, class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.timewindowed.TimeWindowedCustomer]).
If that class (Vehicle) (or superclass thereof) is not a @PlanningEntity annotated class, maybe your @PlanningSolution annotated class has an incorrect @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty or @PlanningEntityProperty annotated member.
Otherwise, if you're not using the Quarkus extension or Spring Boot starter, maybe that entity class (Vehicle) is missing from your solver configuration.
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.findEntityDescriptorOrFail(SolutionDescriptor.java:729)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.lambda$countUninitializedVariables$16(SolutionDescriptor.java:1047)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.lambda$visitAllEntities$9(SolutionDescriptor.java:936)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.visitAllEntities(SolutionDescriptor.java:950)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.visitAllEntities(SolutionDescriptor.java:936)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.countUninitializedVariables(SolutionDescriptor.java:1046)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.lambda$countUninitialized$15(SolutionDescriptor.java:1041)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.solution.descriptor.SolutionDescriptor.countUninitialized(SolutionDescriptor.java:1041)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(AbstractScoreDirector.java:178)
        at org.optaplanner.constraint.drl.DrlScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution(DrlScoreDirector.java:68)
        at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.DefaultScoreManager.updateScore(DefaultScoreManager.java:53)
        at com.test.vrp.web.rest.PlannerResource.getSolution(PlannerResource.java:182)
        at com.test.vrp.web.rest.PlannerResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a02fe551.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
        at com.test.vrp.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        at com.test.vrp.web.rest.PlannerResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$dfc6fec2.getSolution(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at com.test.vrp.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:40)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2019)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1558)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1423)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: 1) Please add stack trace of the exception. 2) Do you use `solverConfig.xml`? If yes, what are your `<entityClass>` elements there?

Comment: The solverConfig I'm using is the one that is already there from the example: <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Standstill</entityClass>
  <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.Customer</entityClass>
  <entityClass>org.optaplanner.examples.vehiclerouting.domain.timewindowed.TimeWindowedCustomer</entityClass>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is a result of the code being migrated from `optaplanner-examples` to a new project with a different package structure.

This is the important part of the message:

```
A planning entity is an instance of a class (class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.Vehicle)
that is not configured as a planning entity class ([
  class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.Customer,
  class com.test.vrp.domain.planner.timewindowed.TimeWindowedCustomer
]).
```

I suspect the `solverConfig.xml` that you have in your project is *ignored* and that's not necessarily a bad thing or the cause of the issue. The reason I think so is that the FQCNs you shared in the comment are completely different from what's in the exception message. I guess that if you delete your `solverConfig.xml` the exception will remain the same.

The `optaplanner-spring-boot-starter` artifact contains an extension that will automatically discover your `@PlanningSolution` and your `@PlanningEntity` annotated classes provided that they are in a sub-package of your `@SpingBootApplication`. From the exception message, we can see that `Customer` and `TimeWindowedCustomer` have been discovered (despite of what you have in your `solverConfig.xml`) but `com.test.vrp.domain.Standstill` is missing. **Try to fix that**:

1. Make sure `com.test.vrp.domain.Vehicle` extends `com.test.vrp.domain.Standstill`.
2. Make sure `com.test.vrp.domain.Standstill` is in your project in the `com.test.vrp.domain` package.
3. Check that `com.test.vrp.domain.Standstill` has the `@PlanningEntity` annotation.

Also check that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the `com.test.vrp` or `com.test.vrp.domain` package.

Comment: When you say make Vehicle extends Standstill, that matches up with the part of the error message about "If that class (Vehicle) (or superclass thereof) is not a @PlanningEntity annotated class,". With the optaplanner-spring-boot-starter, Can the Vehicle implement an interface that is annotated as a PlanningEntity, or does it need to extend a class that is?

Comment: I wrote `extends` but I meant `implements` obviously, because Standstill is an interface. It makes no difference if Vehicle inherits the annotation from an interface or a superclass. The problem is that your `@PlanningEntity Standstill` is not discovered by the solver factory. In plain Java it's discovered using the solverConfig.xml. In Spring Boot and Quarkus, it's auto-discovered using the framework's bean scanning mechanism. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. There's definitely more going on than just discovering Standstill. I have something that's functional, but I've had to modify lots of the example to get it to run. There's probably an elegant way to make it work with the starter, but it's beyond me.

Comment: See https://github.com/yurloc/demo-optaplanner-example if that helps.

Comment: My answer may be completely off. In that case would you mind posting a new answer sharing your solution?

Comment: That example was exactly what I needed. I was confusing myself because of errors related to the json conversion of the solution. Thanks for the help.